# How to set database login infos (connection info) for crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have an application (NOT MY Coding) which have a lot of crystal reports.
the problem I'm facing is that every time i open a crystal report it asks for login username and password.

after a little search i found that i have to set the connectioninfo for the report at run time and i found some solution but when i looked at the code of the application i didn't find it as i was expecting.

the frmviewrpt (the form that has the crystal report viewer) have some thing like this:

```
RptProBalance rptProductBalance = new RptProBalance();
rptProductBalance.RecordSelectionFormula = getBalanceRptSelection();
rptProductBalance.Refresh();
allReportViewer.ReportSource = rptProductBalance;
```

the RptProBalance() (the cs file that is extended from the RptProBalance.rpt file):

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // <auto-generated>
 //     This code was generated by a tool.
 //     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.42
 //
 //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
 //     the code is regenerated.
 // </auto-generated>
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 namespace minfatora {
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using CrystalDecisions.ReportSource;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;


public class RptProBalance : ReportClass {

    public RptProBalance() {
    }

    public override string ResourceName {
        get {
            return "RptProBalance.rpt";
        }
        set {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section ReportHeaderSection1 {
        get {
            return this.ReportDefinition.Sections[0];
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section PageHeaderSection1 {
        get {
            return this.ReportDefinition.Sections[1];
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section GroupHeaderSection1 {
        get {
            return this.ReportDefinition.Sections[2];
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section DetailSection1 {
        get {
            return this.ReportDefinition.Sections[3];
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section GroupFooterSection1 {
        get {
            return this.ReportDefinition.Sections[4];
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section ReportFooterSection1 {
        get {
            return this.ReportDefinition.Sections[5];
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section PageFooterSection1 {
        get {
            return this.ReportDefinition.Sections[6];
        }
    }
}

[System.Drawing.ToolboxBitmapAttribute(typeof(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions), "report.bmp")]
public class CachedRptProBalance : Component, ICachedReport {

    public CachedRptProBalance() {
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public virtual bool IsCacheable {
        get {
            return true;
        }
        set {
            // 
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public virtual bool ShareDBLogonInfo {
        get {
            return false;
        }
        set {
            // 
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public virtual System.TimeSpan CacheTimeOut {
        get {
            return CachedReportConstants.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
        }
        set {
            // 
        }
    }

    public virtual CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument CreateReport()      {
        RptProBalance rpt = new RptProBalance();
        rpt.Site = this.Site;
        return rpt;
    }

    public virtual string GetCustomizedCacheKey(RequestContext request) {
        String key = null;
        // // The following is the code used to generate the default
        // // cache key for caching report jobs in the ASP.NET Cache.
        // // Feel free to modify this code to suit your needs.
        // // Returning key == null causes the default cache key to
        // // be generated.
        // 
        // key = RequestContext.BuildCompleteCacheKey(
        //     request,
        //     null,       // sReportFilename
        //     this.GetType(),
        //     this.ShareDBLogonInfo );
        return key;
    }
}
 }
```

I have no clue where exactly I'm supposed to make the connection info and pass it to the report.

Comment: Did this use to work but then stop working? My suspicion is that the user login and/or password changed and it needs to be updated in the .rpt file.

Comment: it was and STILL working but i have to provide the password of the connection every time i open a report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ConnectionInfo crconnectioninfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    ReportDocument cryrpt = new ReportDocument();
    TableLogOnInfos crtablelogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
    TableLogOnInfo crtablelogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

    Tables CrTables;

    crconnectioninfo.ServerName = "localhost";
    crconnectioninfo.DatabaseName = "dbclients";
    crconnectioninfo.UserID = "ssssssss";
    crconnectioninfo.Password = "xxxxxxx";  


  cryrpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\rpts\\" + dealerInfo.ResourceName);

        CrTables = cryrpt.Database.Tables;

        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtablelogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtablelogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crconnectioninfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtablelogoninfo);
        }


        cryrpt.RecordSelectionFormula = getCustInfoRptSelection();
        cryrpt.Refresh();

        allReportViewer.ReportSource = cryrpt;
```

Comment: while it works, performance is horrible. Adapted for subreports, it can take 10 seconds for simple report with just 1 subreport.

Comment: Where is ConnectionInfo class imported from?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to supply it via code, then in your case it looks like you'd go into that datasource that is calling your .rpt file and set it there. Here is an example from my blog in VB.Net. This code will go through all sub reports and the main report and update the connection strings (this assumes, that all reports/subreports are connecting to the same database, if not, you could use pieces of this code to update individual sub reports).

It would be used something like this (although, you're binding to a viewer probably and not exporting, so you could ignore that, this is just for example).

```
    Using rd As New ReportDocument
        rd.Load("C:\Temp\CrystalReports\InternalAccountReport.rpt")
        rd.ApplyNewServer("serverName or DSN", "databaseUsername", "databasePassword")
        rd.ApplyParameters("AccountNumber=038PQRX922;", True)
        rd.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "c:\temp\test.pdf")
        rd.Close()
    End Using

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\temp\test.pdf")
```

Here is the extension method module:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports

Namespace Extensions

''' <summary>
''' A set of extension methods to make manually working with Crystal Reports easier.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>
''' Pieces of this code started in March of 2004 and have evolved over the last 8 years.
''' </remarks>
Public Module CrystalReportExtensions

    '*********************************************************************************************************************
    '
    '            Module:  CrystalReportExtensions
    '      Initial Date:  03/26/2004
    '      Last Updated:  05/22/2012
    '     Programmer(s):  Blake Pell
    '
    '*********************************************************************************************************************

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Applies a new server name, SQL username and password to a ReportDocument.  This method can be used with any number
    ''' of database providers.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub ApplyNewServer(ByVal report As ReportDocument, serverName As String, username As String, password As String)

        For Each subReport As ReportDocument In report.Subreports
            For Each crTable As Table In subReport.Database.Tables
                Dim loi As TableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
                loi.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = serverName
                loi.ConnectionInfo.UserID = username
                loi.ConnectionInfo.Password = password
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(loi)
            Next
        Next

        'Loop through each table in the report and apply the new login information (in our case, a DSN)
        For Each crTable As Table In report.Database.Tables
            Dim loi As TableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
            loi.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = serverName
            loi.ConnectionInfo.UserID = username
            loi.ConnectionInfo.Password = password

            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(loi)
            'If your DatabaseName is changing at runtime, specify the table location. 
            'crTable.Location = ci.DatabaseName & ".dbo." & crTable.Location.Substring(crTable.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)
        Next

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Applies a new server name to the ReportDocument.  This method is SQL Server specific if integratedSecurity is True.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="report"></param>
    ''' <param name="serverName">The name of the new server.</param>
    ''' <param name="integratedSecurity">Whether or not to apply integrated security to the ReportDocument.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub ApplyNewServer(report As ReportDocument, serverName As String, integratedSecurity As Boolean)

        For Each subReport As ReportDocument In report.Subreports
            For Each crTable As Table In subReport.Database.Tables
                Dim loi As TableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
                loi.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = serverName

                If integratedSecurity = True Then
                    loi.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = True
                End If

                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(loi)
            Next
        Next

        'Loop through each table in the report and apply the new login information (in our case, a DSN)
        For Each crTable As Table In report.Database.Tables
            Dim loi As TableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
            loi.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = serverName

            If integratedSecurity = True Then
                loi.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = True
            End If

            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(loi)
            'If your DatabaseName is changing at runtime, specify the table location. 
            'crTable.Location = ci.DatabaseName & ".dbo." & crTable.Location.Substring(crTable.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)
        Next

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Applies a new database name to all of the tables in the Crystal Report.  If you do not wish to use a schemaName, pass
    ''' a blank string in for it.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="report">The Crystal Report document.</param>
    ''' <param name="databaseName">The name of the database.</param>
    ''' <param name="schemaName">The schema name if necessary.  If this is not needed, pass a blank in.</param>
    ''' <remarks>Depending on your database server, this may require a schema also.  For instance, in SQL Server
    ''' you may need NorthWind.dbo. </remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub ApplyNewDatabaseName(ByVal report As ReportDocument, databaseName As String, schemaName As String)
        Dim prefix As String = ""

        If schemaName <> "" Then
            prefix = String.Format("{0}.{1}.", databaseName, schemaName)
        Else
            prefix = String.Format("{0}.", databaseName)
        End If

        'Loop through each table in the report and apply the new database name
        For Each crTable As Table In report.Database.Tables
            'If your DatabaseName is changing at runtime, specify the table location. 
            crTable.Location = String.Format("{0}{1}", prefix, crTable.Location.Substring(crTable.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1))
        Next
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Sets the Username, Password and ServerName property and/or the UseTrustedConnection property with the values listed in the
    ''' provided connection string.  Currently, only Sql Server is supported for automatically loading values from a connection
    ''' string.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sqlConnectionString"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub ApplyCredentialsFromConnectionString(report As ReportDocument, ByVal sqlConnectionString As String)
        ' Apply the connection information from the web.config file.
        Dim cb As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sqlConnectionString)

        If cb.IntegratedSecurity = False Then
            ApplyNewServer(report, cb.DataSource, cb.UserID, cb.Password)
        Else
            ApplyNewServer(report, cb.DataSource, True)
        End If
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Checks to see if a parameter name exists in the reports parameter fields.  This only checks the top level of
    ''' the report.  The top level should propagate down any parameters that need to be passed down.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="paramName"></param>
    ''' <param name="report"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function DoesParameterExist(ByVal report As ReportDocument, ByVal paramName As String) As Boolean

        If report Is Nothing Or report.ParameterFields Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If

        For Each param As ParameterField In report.ParameterFields
            If paramName = param.Name Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next

        Return False
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Takes a parameter string and places them in the corresponding parameters for the report.  The parameter string must 
    ''' be semi-colon delimited with the parameter inside of that delimited with an equal sign.  E.g.<br /><br />
    ''' 
    ''' <code>
    ''' lastName=Pell;startDate=1/1/2012;endDate=1/7/2012
    ''' </code>
    ''' 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="report">The Crystal Reports ReportDocument object.</param>
    ''' <param name="parameters">A parameter string representing name/values.  See the summary for usage.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub ApplyParameters(report As ReportDocument, parameters As String)
        ApplyParameters(report, parameters, False)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Takes a parameter string and places them in the corresponding parameters for the report.  The parameter string must 
    ''' be semi-colon delimited with the parameter inside of that delimited with an equal sign.  E.g.<br /><br />
    ''' 
    ''' <code>
    ''' lastName=Pell;startDate=1/1/2012;endDate=1/7/2012
    ''' </code>
    ''' 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="report">The Crystal Reports ReportDocument object.</param>
    ''' <param name="parameters">A parameter string representing name/values.  See the summary for usage.</param>
    ''' <param name="removeInvalidParameters">If True, parameters that don't exist in the Crystal Report will
    ''' be removed.  If False, these parameters will be left in and an exception will be thrown listing
    ''' the offending parameter name.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub ApplyParameters(report As ReportDocument, parameters As String, removeInvalidParameters As Boolean)

        ' No parameters (or valid parameters) were provided.
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters) = True Or parameters.Contains("=") = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Get rid of any trailing or leading semi-colons that would mess up the splitting.
        parameters = parameters.Trim(";")

        ' The list of parameters split out by the semi-colon delimiter
        Dim parameterList As String() = parameters.Split(Chr(Asc(";")))

        For Each parameter As String In parameterList
            ' nameValue(0) = Parameter Name, nameValue(0) = Value
            Dim nameValue As String() = parameter.Split(Chr(Asc("=")))

            ' Validate that the parameter exists and throw a legit exception that describes it as opposed to the
            ' Crystal Report COM Exception that gives you little detail.  
            If report.DoesParameterExist(nameValue(0)) = False And removeInvalidParameters = False Then
                Throw New Exception(String.Format("The parameter '{0}' does not exist in the Crystal Report.", nameValue(0)))
            ElseIf report.DoesParameterExist(nameValue(0)) = False And removeInvalidParameters = True Then
                Continue For
            End If

            ' The ParameterFieldDefinition MUST be disposed of otherwise memory issues will occur, that's why
            ' we're going the "using" route.  Using should Dispose of it even if an Exception occurs.
            Using pfd As ParameterFieldDefinition = report.DataDefinition.ParameterFields.Item(nameValue(0))
                Dim pValues As ParameterValues
                Dim parm As ParameterDiscreteValue
                pValues = New ParameterValues

                parm = New ParameterDiscreteValue
                parm.Value = nameValue(1)

                pValues.Add(parm)
                pfd.ApplyCurrentValues(pValues)
            End Using
        Next

    End Sub

End Module

End Namespace
```

Comment: Hi, could you share the extensoion methods?, the website is down. Thanks

Comment: The cloud ate my site, I no longer have access to it and I haven't moved the domain yet.  I'm going to update my answer with the extension method module.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the datasource is set up in the .rpt file. Open the .rpt file in the crystal reports designer (or VS if you have the add on) and choose "verify database". Once you have supplied this info and saved, it shouldn't do that anymore. The password was probably changed since the original setup.

Comment: did that and still asking for password.

Comment: Did it show a query or stored procedure as the datasource in the .rpt file?

Comment: yes the data source is a query(view) not a table. will that be different?

Comment: The way your report is designed, the datasource is set in the report designer. You'll have to thoroughly look through the file and make sure that there aren't multiple data sources set up. Maybe there is a subreport that has it's own data source and that is what's not set properly?

Comment: The reason I asked about the query/store procedure is because the way we do our reports is by using an .xsd file as the datasource in the designer. Then in our c# code, we populate a class that follows the structure of the .xsd file with our data and set a List<OurClass> as the datasource in the code. So many ways to do this, it makes it hard to debug without being hands on.