# Database login screen in Crystal Reports viewer .NET

Tags: c++, .net, crystal-reports, viewer

I have run into an issue when testing my Crystal report viewer.

When I am trying to view an report from the primary app(the viewer is called from this app) it prompts a login screen, containing :

- Server Name : *(field unavailable to edit)*
- Database : *(field unavailable to edit)*
- Login ID : *(here it shows my login id)*
- Password : *(Editable field)*

If I enter the password and press finish the report is viewed without problem. I have googled the problem, but the results I have read only made me more confused.

What could be the trigger of these screen? I could not find in code the part that pops up the screen.

My viewer is created in C++ .NET using SAP DLL's for .NET platform.

I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't even a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the report connection info programmatically otherwise it will ask you with the screen you are seeing. You can google "Crystal reports Connection info" to find samples how to do that. Here is one for C#:
[How to set database login infos (connection info) for crystal report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002957/how-to-set-database-login-infos-connection-info-for-crystal-report)

Answer (score 0):

Its all good and well to set the datasource location programically, but in some cases this will not solve the problem at all. I discovered something cool.

Look at this screen shot:

[image]

This is wrong. No matter if you try to set the datasource location a 1000 times. Even if you try to see what is wring in your code, you will NOT fix it by code alone.

This screenshot shows how these settings should look like:

[image]

So that is the problem.

Question is, how do I get to this screen? Ah easy-peasy.

Look at the screenshots in their order respectively:

[image]

You will see something like this then:

[image]

So make sure these are set to the last screenshot and all your problems will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I changed database connection to:

- OLE DB (ADO)

and selected

- Microsoft OLE Provider for SQL Server

and that solves my problems.
Now you can change your database on code as like you want to.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you set your data source in your report, you probably authenticated in **windows mode** and it caused that the user name and password didn't assign to that report and you must authenticate in **SQL Server Authentication mode**. So you should configure an **ODBC** connection in SQL Server Authentication mode with specific name and always set and verify your data source by it.