# How to hide Enter Parameter Value when navigate to next page in crystal reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In my crystal reports when i navigate to next page its asking to enter parameters values again , I already passed parameters value when run crystal reports. Why its asking again when navigate to next page?

I tried some solutions but its still asking for parameters values when navigate to next page ?

i tried this code :

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = false;
```

I expect when click next page button to use same parameters values and not asking again to Enter values.

This is my code:

I have my data in another window in datagrid view and there is hyperlink print result when click on it i send the primary key by using query string to the crystal report window 
this is the hyper link code

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Options</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1"  NavigateUrl='<%#"/RPT/WebForm1.aspx?order_id=" +Eval("Request number")+"&DEPT ID=" +Eval("DEPT ID")+"&Test Id=" +Eval("Test Id")%>' runat="server">Print Result</asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

and this is page load code in the other window :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

              TXTORDERID.Text = Request.QueryString["order_id"].ToString();
                TXTDEPTID.Text = Request.QueryString["DEPT ID"].ToString();
                TXTTESTID.Text = Request.QueryString["Test Id"].ToString();
                ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
                ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
                ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
                ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();



                        paramField.Name = "@ORDER_ID";
                        paramDiscreteValue.Value = TXTORDERID.Text.ToString();
                        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
                        paramFields.Add(paramField);

                        paramField = new ParameterField(); 
                        paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();  
                        paramField.Name = "@deptid";
                        paramDiscreteValue.Value = TXTDEPTID.Text.ToString();
                        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
                        paramFields.Add(paramField);

                        CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
                        reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/RPT/RPT_RESULT.rpt"));
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
                        reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("DBA", "2006");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Post code, and also check if it is because of Postback?

Comment: @JulyOrdinary , i addded if (!IsPostBack) and window for parameters now hided but another window appeared now asking for further information user name and password for database but i already added it in the code reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("DBA", "2006"); how to hide also this window ?

Comment: Try following to check if code is missing something https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002957/how-to-set-database-login-infos-connection-info-for-crystal-report

Comment: @JulyOrdinary yes its working thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use the following code in your page load or in the button where you call crystal report code also for the message show when navigate to next page under your code add the following code it will hide the message "The report you requested requires further information "

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   // your code inside 


    var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    connectionInfo.ServerName = "server_name";
    connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "database_name";
    connectionInfo.UserID = "database_user_name";
    connectionInfo.Password = "database_password";
    connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;
    connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;

for (int i = 0; i < CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Count; i++)
{
    CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo[i].ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
}
}
```

Comment: i addded if (!IsPostBack) and window for parameters now hided but another window appeared now asking for further information user name and password for database but i already added it in the code reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("DBA", "2006");                                           how to hide also this window ?